# The Count and GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT does not group one field and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `user` VARCHAR(15),
  `userid` INTEGER,
  `user_id` INTEGER,
  `ipaddr` VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO tab
  (`id`, `user`, `userid`, `user_id`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Client', '10', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('2', 'admin1', '1', '0', '2.2.2.2'),
  ('3', 'Client', '3', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('4', 'admin2', '5', '0', '3.3.3.3'),
  ('5', 'Client', '12', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('6', 'admin1', '1', '0', '2.2.2.2'),
  ('7', 'Client', '21', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('9', 'Sub-Client 20', '35', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('9', 'Sub-Client 20', '35', '0', '4.4.4.4'),
  ('9', 'Sub-Client 20', '35', '0', '1.1.1.1'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'Client', '25', '0', '6.6.6.6'),
  ('8', 'user1@gmail.com', '30', '0', '7.7.7.7'),
  ('8', 'user1@gmail.com', '30', '0', '7.7.7.7');

SELECT
  COUNT(ipaddr), `ipaddr`, GROUP_CONCAT(`userid` ORDER BY `userid` DESC  ) userid
FROM tab
WHERE `user` = 'Client' OR `user` LIKE 'Sub-Client%' OR `user` LIKE '%@%'
GROUP BY `ipaddr`, `userid`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER By COUNT(ipaddr) DESC
```

This is the result:

```
COUNT(ipaddr) ipaddr userid
2            7.7.7.7 30,30
9            6.6.6.6 25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25
1            4.4.4.4 12
1            4.4.4.4 21
2            4.4.4.4 35,35
1            1.1.1.1 3
1            1.1.1.1 10
1            1.1.1.1 35
```

You may see it live: https://dbfiddle.uk/N8PO_qTN

The issue is:

1. The `userid` in the output has duplicated (like 30 and 25)
2. One IP is repeated multiple times (like 1.1.1.1)

What I'm going to have this as the expected output:

```
COUNT(ipaddr) ipaddr userid
9            6.6.6.6 25
4            4.4.4.4 12, 21, 35
3            1.1.1.1 3, 10, 35
2            7.7.7.7 30
1            4.4.4.4 12
```

Comment: 1) see accepted answer to the duplicate question for getting distinct values in group_concat 2) if you want to get the results by IP address only, then why do you group by user id as well?